# running all the batch files in a given directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, infinite-loop

I have the following batch script for running all the files in a directory 
.However this script is an infinite loop and keeps on repeating . is there a way to stop the script when it finishes the last batch file the following is my script

```
@echo off 
 for /R %%x in (*.bat) do ( 
 call "%%x" 
)
pause
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're including this script in your current directory, it is run with the others: recursive/infinite call.

Either put this script one level up, cd in the directory of the bat files and call it with `..\yourscript.bat`

Or you could filter out the current script in your loop:

```
@echo off 
 for /R %%x in (*.bat) do (
 if not "%%x" == "%~0" call "%%x" 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you start the batch in the same folder as all the other batchfiles, move this batch to another folder and adjust the `(*.bat)` path to `(other_folder\*.bat)`.
Another way would be to check if the batch is the same as the one that is executed and skip that one.